# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I written an PHP script that execute an SOAP request to send some data and upload an `base64binary` using soap_client in PHP 7.2.14.

After execute the SOAP request with a small amount of data (small file < 60 Kb) the request will pass. If I add a bigger file to upload (>80 Kb) the request will fail and gives this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP`.

I checked `default_socket_timeout` on the server and increased it.I also tried  `base64_econde` the string, but SOAP is already encoding it by itself.

My code:

```
//WS SETTINGS
$wsdl = "https://ws.eye-move.nl/WoningDocument.asmx?WSDL";
$ns = 'http://ws.eye-move.nl/WoningDocument';


// SOAP client
$params = array ('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 180);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $params);

//COLLECT DATA FOR UPLOADING
$RecID = '34244701';
$filename = 'Testfile-'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.pdf';
$filecontent = file_get_contents('temp/test.pdf');

//SET HEADERS
$headerBody = array(
    'Username' => $login,
    'Password' => $password,
    'Customer' => $partnerID
);

$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'AuthHeader', $headerBody);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$data = array(
    'WoningID' => $RecID,
    'WoningDocumentBestand' => array('Bestandsnaam'=>$filename,'Bestand'=>$filecontent),
    'WoningDocumentType' => 'DocumentType',
    'Omschrijving' => 'Description',
    'Volgorde' => '1'
);
$result = $client->Add(array('Gegevens' => $data));
```

Full exeption:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP request in /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php:65 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'ws.eye-m...', 'ws.eye-m...', 1, 0) #1 /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php(65): SoapClient->__call('Add', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php on line 65
```

That below code I have wrote on Line 65 is:

```
$result = $client->Add(array('Gegevens' => $data));
```

Any idea why small files will be send successful and bigger files (>80 Kb) will fail?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you post more info about the exception and do you know if the service you are trying to consume has any limit on the file size?

Comment: The service is not limited, only limit is an  timeout limit of 2 minutes they told me. I get de error within 1 second after fireing.

Comment: The Full exeption: 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP request in /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php:65 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://ws.eye-m...', 'http://ws.eye-m...', 1, 0) #1 /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php(65): SoapClient->__call('Add', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/acceptatie.nl/httpdocs/sendrapport3.php on line 65

Line 65 is:$result = $client->Add(array('Gegevens' => $data));

Comment: Did you find the solution? i have exactly the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and tried below solution and it was worked for me.
But i don't know which values you passed in header.
Please add

```
#) libxml_disable_entity_loader(false); // above the WS SETTINGS and try it.
```

Comment: What you getting ?? did you enabled soap in php.ini ??
if yes then after changed file did you restart server??

Comment: Yes, SOAP is enabled. I can use the script, but only with very small base64 strings as data. So it's working only with very small files <60 kb.